# Displaying Different Elements with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Using [Spring Security Expressions](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions-basic) I would like to display a `select` element if a user has a ROLE_ADMIN, else display an `input` element if the user has `ROLE_USER` only. i.e., The `input` should not display to the ROLE_ADMIN (else both a `select` and `input` would display)

Here's what I've tried so far

```
<!-- If ROLE_ADMIN -->
<select sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    <option value="" th:text="Select"></option>
    <option 
        th:each="temp : *{username.entrySet()}" 
        th:value="${temp.key}" 
        th:text="${temp.value}"></option>
</select>

<!-- If strictly ROLE_USER -->
<input 
    sec:ifAllGranted="ROLE_USER" 
    type="text" 
    th:readonly="true" 
    th:field="*{username}"
/>
```

This method however still displays both input and select elements to ROLE_ADMIN; is there a better implementation or case statement I could be using to accomplish this?

Comment: Does the user that has `ROLE_ADMIN` also have `ROLE_USER`?

Comment: Cant you use hasRole('ROLE_USER') && !hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ?